# Modal mask appears over modal element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, modalpopup

I have a modal pop up that needs to be fired from an article in a module, I need to have this format. The modal pop up is behind the modal backdrop and positions in relation to the module.
I get that its taking the parent relative position of the article in the module but I need to stop it without breaking the page layout.
In other words I need this page: http://my-healthy-living.co.uk/weight-management/herbalife-core-nutrition-formula-1-meal-replacement-shakes

To behave like the pop ups in this page :http://my-healthy-living.co.uk/weight-management/herbalife-protein-shake-solutions

With it in front of the backdrop and central to the screen. Please help!

Comment: Show your modal code, please. If you're simply using a Joomla extension to implement them, this question is off-topic.

Comment: I am using bootstrap default modal pop up, not sure how to show in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore please, was trying to post comment on my phone but added as an answer!!!  Can't find delete on the darn app....

He means the actual code for the modal and any relevant JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: Fixed it thanks; kinda. Found some JavaScript that moved the html div. Meant I could move it away from any parent div that was messing up the css.